# ¿Cómo puedo consumir un servicio web(REST-ASP .NET-WEB API 2) alojada en un servidor externo IIS 8.5 en WIndows Server 2012R?

Tags: http, iis, windows-server-2012, ip, webapi

Hice un servicio web en .NET 4.5(Web API 2) en mi PC (Win 10) y lo he alojado en el IIS 8.5 de un servidor en el puerto 80 con SO Windows Server 2012R,instalé Chrome y usé POSTMAN para probar los servicios así: "**localhost\IQSOFT\pedidos**","**IQSOFT\pedido\detalles**",etc y todo me funcionó bien. Ahora yo quiero consumirlo desde una app Android y para ello ya me han habilitado la salida a una ip pública de ese servidor (192.X.X.XX), adicionalmente me comentaron que está "nateada" a esta IP pública 200.XX.XXX.XX Entré remotamente al servidor y probé los servicios con la IP pública de nuevo con el POSTMAN de esta forma:"**200.XX.XXX.XX\pedidos**". Incluso ingresé desde Chrome a "**200.XX.XXX.XX/IQSOFT/help**" y todo bien me salió lo que esperaba(TODO DESDE EL SERVIDOR).

Lo que no entiendo es que al momento de probarlo desde mi PC, por ejemplo, ingresando a "**200.XX.XXX.XX/IQSOFT/help**" o probándolo,también con el POSTMAN; me rechaza la conexión, nunca puedo hacer peticiones.
¿Necesito otra configuración? Yo no hice la configuración de salida a IP pública del servidor y he escuchado que el firewall también interviene en estos casos, ¿Puede que hallan obviado configurar dicho firewall u otra configuración?
Gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día Amigo, no veo respuestas a tu request. ¿Cómo lo solucionaste? Gracias.